# Sending Errors Back to Form: Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble getting the form validation library to send my form errors back to my form in this case.

I have a controller that handles uploading images called addImage.php. This controller only handles the do_upload processing. I have a view called uploadimage.php that contains the upload form and submits to /addImage/do_upload.

The upload form is loaded on the front page of my website using a template in code igniter using

```
<?php $this->load->view('uploadimage'); ?>
```

The front page controller is contained in home.php

Right now after validation fails, I'm just redirecting to the homepage which clearly doesn't load the errors back (in addImage.php)

```
if($this->_submit_validate() == FALSE)
        {
                redirect('/', 'location');
                return;         
        }
```

How can I redirect to my template_front.php while keeping those errors. Can I somehow call my home.php controller from the uploadimage.php controller to do this? I've confused myself trying to explain it! If this is totally unclear, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller), you are suppose to simply re-load the view file on failure.

```
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('myform');
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }
```

a redirect generates a new server request which flushes the validation error information.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that my view is not the complete webpage - I have a header view and footer view and a template view that compile the full web page so my form is just a <div><form></form></div> sort of thing, so if I just load that view it kills the rest of the page.

Comment: Then just reload all the views, the same way you do when you initially load the form.

Comment: I think I just need to learn how to call the controller home.php's index method and it will work - is there a simple way to do this without having to copy and paste the code?

Comment: If you mean from within `home.php` then just do `$this->index()`

Comment: You could also load your view as a string $this->load->view('myform', true) which will not kill the rest of your page

Comment: what would he do with it once it is a string?

Comment: This is by far the best answer

Comment: The issue is that it's not from within home.php. I'm trying to calling load the index from addImage.php, maybe I should refactor my code some, but I want to be able to put my uploadimage form on more pages than just the home page, so I made it it's own controller.

Comment: yeah,  I would need to see more code to suggest how to organize it, but addImage sounds like it might make a good model function if you are processing images and doing database interaction.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I'm doing it takes the upload, renames the file, puts it in the right directory, and upadtes the database using doctrine. I'm not sure how to factor that into a model though - perhaps I should open a new question?

Comment: Yes open a new question, and be sure to add your controller routine for addImage, and your form validation code, the more code you post here the better people can help.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to post the question yesterday - I have now put it up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864172/refactoring-controller-to-model-in-code-igniter Thanks for your help, voted you up.

Answer (score 0):

on validation failure you should reload the form. May be you want to add a button to concel uploading.
On the view, you should add some tag to show errors (there are lots of info about validation helpares) like in:

```
<?=form_open_multipart("/personas/savefoto", array('class' => "form3") )?>
            <h3><?=$heading?></h3>

            <div class="center">
                <?php echo '<strong>'.mb_convert_case($record['nombre'].' '.$record['apellido1'].' '.$record['apellido2'], MB_CASE_TITLE).'</strong><br/>';
                if( file_exists("fotos/e".MATRIZ."/b".$record['id'].".jpg")){
                    ?>
                    <img class="foto" src="<?php echo base_url()."fotos/e".MATRIZ."/b".$record['id']?>.jpg"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <?php
                } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="imagen">Nueva imagen <br/>(jpg, gif o png)</label>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
                <br/>

                    <?php if(isset($error_image)) echo '<p class="error">'.$error_image.'</p>'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row center">
                <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="location.href='/system.php/personas/admin';">
            </div>
            <?=form_close();?>
```

look for the if(isset($error_image))

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the validation_errors() function and set them to a session variable

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('form_errors', validation_errors()));
```

then access them on your redirect page.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('form_errors');
$this->session->unset_userdata('form_errors'); // prevent them from being stored past use
```